# Using cURL - maintain cookies & sessions, etc

Tags: php, curl

Say I make a request to log into a site, using cURL.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URLs["sign_in"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cj.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cj.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $URLs["home"]);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Now, say I make another request to get another page. How can I keep the same sessions & cookies I had (in the previous code) alive in my next request? I tried this, not working:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URLs["enter"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cj.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cj.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $URLs["home"]);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

BTW, this is all in the same PHP file.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me.

Check that you have permission for `cj.txt` to be writeable. Or, if `cj.txt` doesn't exist, make sure you have permission to create it (directory execute permissions, I believe).